# How to check a mail ,weather it is existing or not before inserting a record

Tags: apex, email

I have a email field on an object.User can enter the data from VF page into this object.I was just checking weather there is any provision to check the given email-id is valid or not.  Its not something like just syntax check, i want to do an actual check like alex125324@sampledomain.com , this emails syntax was perfect but there might be no email id with the mentioned one, is there any way to check this through apex coding.

thank's, happy to hear any suggestions

Comment: Other than validating the syntax of the email address (having an @ and a '.com', '.net', et), the only way to validate an email address' actual existence would be through a 3rd party service using a web services callout.

Comment: thanks @crmprogdev , it mean we have to send any test email or just a callout.

Comment: What I'm speaking of would be a callout to a subscription service that you'd pay for to validate email addresses for you. I don't think you'd want to send confirmation or 'test' emails to validate addresses for you unless they served an additional purpose. In my view, that would be a management decision as part of their marketing or other strategy (depending on what the data is used for).

Comment: There is no way that you check for a domain as there are thousands of email domains. If you need only specific email domains then you could use string functions to validate.